# External Monitor Connected to Integrated Graphics Instead of Dedicated GPU(Laptop)

Tags: nvidia

I'm facing an issue where my external monitor is being connected to the integrated graphics card on my laptop, despite having a dedicated GPU. Here are the steps I've taken to troubleshoot:

Checked BIOS/UEFI settings: Confirmed that there's no specific option to set the dedicated GPU as the primary display.

Physx Settings: Set Physx to use the dedicated GPU, but the issue persists.
Device Manager: Uninstalled both integrated and dedicated graphics adapters, then restarted to reinstall drivers.

Switchable Graphics Settings: Checked for any specific software or settings related to switchable graphics but found none.

Updated Drivers: Ensured that both integrated and dedicated graphics drivers are up to date.
Despite these efforts, my external monitor continues to be connected to the integrated graphics. Are there any additional steps or solutions I can try to force the connection to the dedicated GPU? My laptop has an HDMI port, and there's a Type-C or but that doesn't support DisplayPort.

Laptop Details:

Manufacturer: Lenovo
Model: IdeaPad Gaming 3-15IHU6 - Type 82K1004EIN
GPU: NVIDIA RTX350